# fearing for someone

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice, writing

**He was fearing for the hostages.**

Is this enough to be understood? Or should it be...

**He was fearing for the hostages' safety.**

or

**He was fearing for the hostages' lives.**

Comment: All three are fine. Obviously the last two are more specific. Using simple past may be better depending on the situation, but there are scenarios where the past continuous would work.

Comment: Yeah, I understood the first one at first reading, so I guess that's a sign that it's pretty good :)